# Restart FlipClock after time expire

Tags: javascript, flipclock

How can I restart flipclock again after time completed?

```
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {
    clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 10, {
        clockFace: 'Counter',
        autoStart: true,
        countdown: true
    });

});
```

I want to start again the counter after 10 sec on a condition. What I have tried is

```
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {
    clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 10, {
        clockFace: 'Counter',
        autoStart: true,
        countdown: true,
        callbacks: {
            stop: function() {
               //my custom condition here if(not_free){start showing again}
                clock.start();
            }
        }
    });

});
```

But this not worked. any idea?

Comment: problem solved after an wokaround

Comment: and the workaround was what? (to help others with this question.)

Comment: see one answer below. Problem was the counter value is finished this is why an error show in console. After setting time again with `setTime()` in `stop` callback clock restart successfully

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add this line into the **stop** callback function.

```
clock.setTime(10);
```

Final codes:

```js
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {
    clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 10, {
        clockFace: 'Counter',
        autoStart: true,
        countdown: true,
        callbacks: {
            stop: function() {
                clock.setTime(10);
                clock.start();
            }
        }
    });

});
```